# yii, get data from $_POST

Tags: php, yii

i want to get a single data from $_POST, the field on the form is called "parametro", and its being saved on $_POST['Caracterizacion'], i want to get this "parametro" and save it as string on a var, how to get this data?

Comment: You should try to use: print_r($_POST) to see info about POST params. BTW, you can try  $_POST['Caracterizacion']['parametro'] to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_POST['Caracterizacion']['parametro']
```

Answer (score 0):

So the field on the form is parametro? I'm going to assume the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="parametero" id="param_1"/>
```

In which case you would access the contents of that field like so:

```
$var = $_POST['parametero'];
```

This assumes the method attribute of the form element that this input element is in is set to POST

If I am assuming incorrectly, please elaborate further and provide at least your html.

Comment: it gives me an error "Undefined index: Parametro", and yes, the field on the form is parametro

Comment: still gives me "Undefined index: parametro"

Comment: Can you post your full form html please?

Comment: its just 1 field thats called Parametro, but im trying to get this data because i use Yii::app()->request->getParam('Caracterizacion'), or just $_POST['Caracterizacion'] and it gives me an error "Array to string conversion", so i thought it might just because the var is an array and im trying to get just 1 element from it and save it to another var

Comment: This isn't making sense. Can you please just post the full HTML of your form?

Comment: i posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

this is the view:

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'caracterizacion-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'parametro'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'parametro',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>256)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'parametro'); ?>
    </div>




    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget();

 ?>



</div><!-- form -->
```

and this is the action from controller

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Caracterizacion;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Caracterizacion']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Caracterizacion'];
            if($model->save())
            {
                $variable="hola";
                Caracterizacion::model()->columna($variable);
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
            }
            if($model->save() == false)
                var_dump($model->errors);
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

you can see im making a var called variable with the content "hola" and its being taken to a class made on the model, for now it works, but the thing is, i want to replace the "hola" string with just one element on $_POST, when i replace it with $_POST['Caracterizacion'], it gives me an error "Array to string conversion", so i dont know what to do and thats why i ask how to get just 1 element from $_post